# How do I stop my database from rounding to 16 decimal places?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a webpage, where when the user clicks a payment button, a set amount it subtracted from an existing value in the database table. Just to confirm: My page does do this. But the unexpected behaviour of my code is it subtracts the amount, but it doesn't round it. It rounds it to 16 decimal places and I only want 2. See the image below (the bottom row) to see what I mean.

I have tried using the number_format() and round() functions in PHP but I'm not sure why they don't work. Am I using them incorrectly?

[image: Unexpected behaviour in database table]

This is the full code below:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
  $SQL_query = "SELECT ROUND(SUM(Total), 2) AS sum FROM `order_details` WHERE `OrderID` = 95";
  $query_result = mysqli_query($connection, $SQL_query);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
  $total = $row['sum'];
  $number = floatval($total);
  }

  $SQL_Balance = "UPDATE Users SET Balance=(Balance-$number) WHERE UserID = 7";
  mysqli_query($connection, $SQL_Balance);


}
```

Comment: That's due to floating point precision. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php.

Comment: Beyond simple display issues like this, this is why you should never use floating point types to represent currency.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks. So what would you recommend I use instead?

Comment: An integer representing the base currency unit [eg: one cent] or a fixed-point DECIMAL type.

Comment: Related: [Is floating point maths broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: **DO NOT USE FLOAT FOR CURRENCY** Use the dedicated decimal type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a two decimal number you can use ROUND with the following query:

```
UPDATE Users SET Balance=(ROUND(Balance-$number, 2)) WHERE UserID = 7
```